# Got error of Plugin.Connectivity.ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I received an error Cannot Create instance of type 'Plugin.Connectivity.ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceiver'

while compiling my code

```cs
public WelcomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent(); 
    CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += Current_ConnectivityChanged;
}

protected async override void OnAppearing() {
     base.OnAppearing();    
     if(!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected){
     await DisplayAlert("Error Title", "Error Msg", "OK");
     }
     else
     {//do nothing}
}
        
private async void Current_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e){
   if (!e.IsConnected)
   {
       await DisplayAlert("Error Title", "Error Msg", "OK");
   }
   else
   {//do nothing}
}
```

Comment: Did you get the error for iOS and Android? Can you share more details to the compilation error? Did you add the nuget package? Did you initialize the library? What tutorial are you following?

Comment: yes i got Error IOS and Android I did add the Library Plugin.Connectivity thenn  after that the error says "Cannot create and instance of type "Plugin.Connectivity.ConnectivityChangeBroadcastReceived" in java peer type

Comment: Comment all the codes. Only use `CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected; ` to check. Does this throw the same error in WelcomePage method?

Comment: yes @Wendy Zang

Comment: I tested with the code you provided with a new page. There is no error. You could create a new project to install the plugin and test again.